# Joint posterior distribution of $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ in the Normal model

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, prior, posterior

> Find the joint posterior of $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ given Normal data.

I've found the joint prior of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ (where $\displaystyle\sigma^2\sim\chi^{-2}(v_o,v_os_o^2)$ and $\mu\mid\sigma^2\sim N(\mu_o,\frac{\sigma^2}{n_o})$) and likelihood function:

$$\displaystyle\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)\propto(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2]}$$ and $$L(\mu,\sigma^2\mid x_1,\ldots,x_n)\propto (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n-1)s^2+n(\overline x-\mu)^2]}$$ respectively.

So the joint posterior of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ given the data is proportional to the product of both

$$\displaystyle (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2]} (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n-1)s^2+n(\overline x-\mu)^2]}$$

We also know that $$\displaystyle\pi(\mu,\sigma^2)\propto(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2]}$$ is an inverse Gamma normal distribution with parameters $(v_o,s_o^2,\mu_o,n_o).$

I am expected to identify the joint posterior of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ given the data as an inverse Gamma-Normal distribution with similar parameters to $(v_o,s_o^2,\mu_o,n_o)$.

My question is  which are the new parameters and what 'tricks' will I need to apply so that it has the form of inverse Gamma normal distribution?

---

## Update

Checking the answer given,

- How Xi'an passed from $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_o\mu_o^2+n \overline x^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)]}$ to $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_ov_o(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+v_o)^2]}$ ?

Notice that only this $n_o\mu_o^2+n \overline x^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)$ changed to $n_ov_o(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+v_o)^2$ though the term $v_o$ is whether a typo or what is representing? Because it's a new term in the second expression that does not exist in the first expression.

- How can this be represented using R ? How can I plot the prior and posterior distributions, for a certain given parameters?

Comment: There's no trick unless you think "collect terms and simplify" and "equate coefficients of corresponding terms" are tricks.

Comment: @Xi'an I'll edit later about that part.

Comment: @Xi'an Regarding to the first part of your answer, you say that $\pi(\mu|\sigma^2)$ is proportional to an inverse Gamma with parameters $\frac{1}{2}(v_o+n+1,v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2)$. From here I can see the first parameter $\alpha$ but not $\beta$. More specifically, how can I rewrite $n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+n(\overline x-\mu)^2$ so that have the form $n_1(\mu-\mu_1) ?$

Comment: @Xi'an I think I did it, I got $(n_o+n)(\mu-\frac{n_o\mu_o+\overline xn}{n_o+n})^2+constant$. Is it correct?

Comment: The first part of my answer is about $\pi(\sigma^2|\mu)$, not the reverse. And I do not exhibit a perfect square either. The explanation for $\pi(\sigma^2|\mu)$ is found in the second part and I explain there how to exhibit a perfect square for $\mu$. Which indeed leads to$$\frac{n_o+n}{2\sigma^2}[\mu -(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)/(n_o+n)]^2$$

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry I meant a $,$ instead of | here $\pi(\mu|\sigma^2)$. So I was referring to expression $(1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...the joint posterior of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ given the data is
>   proportional to the product of both $$\displaystyle
>  (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2]} (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
>  x-\mu)^2]}$$

which simplifies into
$$\displaystyle
 \pi(\mu,\sigma^2\mid\overline{x},s)\propto(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2]}\,.\tag{1}$$
As a function of $\sigma^2$ only (which means *conditional on everything else*) this expression is proportional to an [inverse Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) conditional posterior density, with parameters $$\frac{1}{2}(v_o+n+1,v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2).$$ *Proportional* means that the above expression is missing a multiplicative constant to turn it a probability density, with integral equal to one, a constant that is called a normalisation term or a *normalising constant*. The [full inverse Gamma density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) is indeed 
\begin{align}\Gamma(\frac{v_o+n+1}{2})^{-1}&\times\left\{\frac{[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2]}{2}\right\}^{\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}}\\
&(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline{x}-\mu)^2]}
\end{align}
Integrating the rhs of (1) with respect to $\sigma^2$ thus produces the missing constant,
$$\Gamma(\frac{v_o+n+1}{2})\times\left\{\frac{[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2]}{2}\right\}^{-\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}}\tag{2}$$
and since integrating the joint posterior on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ in $\sigma^2$ returns the marginal posterior density of $\mu$, 
$$\pi(\mu\mid\overline{x},s) = \int_0^\infty \pi(\mu,\sigma^2\mid\overline{x},s)\,\text{d}\sigma^2$$
this integral (2) is therefore the marginal posterior density of $\mu$, up to a multiplicative constant. With a wee bit of further work, (2) turns into a [Student's $t$ density](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~nmf16/teaching/mas3301/week8.pdf) on $\mu$, with $\frac{v_o+n}{2}$ degrees of freedom, as also described in [our book, Bayesian Essentials](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO) [pages 30-31].

Conversely, if integrating $\mu$ first from (1), the expression becomes proportional to $\pi(\sigma^2\mid\overline{x},s)$: since
\begin{align}\pi(\mu,\sigma^2\mid\overline{x},s) &\propto
(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2]}\\
&=(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_o\mu_o^2+n\overline{x}^2]}\overbrace{\sigma^{-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n_o+n)\mu^2 -2\mu(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)]}}^\text{incomplete normal density}\\
&=(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_o\mu_o^2+n\overline{x}^2]}\underbrace{\sigma^{-1}e^{-\frac{n_o+n}{2\sigma^2}[\mu -(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)/(n_o+n)]^2}}_\text{conditional posterior normal density in $\mu$}\\
&\qquad\qquad\times \underbrace{e^{\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)]}}_\text{missing term in perfect square}\end{align}
integrating $\mu$ out returns
\begin{align}\pi(\sigma^2\mid\mathbf{x})
&\propto (\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_o\mu_o^2+n\overline{x}^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)]}\\
&=(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_ov_o(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+v_o)^2]}
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}n_o\mu_o^2+n\overline{x}^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)
&=n_o\mu_o^2+n\overline{x}^2-\frac{n_o^2}{n_o+n}\mu_o^2-\frac{2n_on}{n_o+n}\mu_o\overline x-\frac{n^2}{n_o+n}\overline{x}^2\\
&= \frac{n_o\mu_o^2}{n_o+n}(n_o+n-n_o)-\frac{2n_on\mu_o\overline x}{n_o+n}+\frac{n\overline{x}^2}{n_o+n}(n_o+n-n)\\
&=\frac{nn_o}{n_o+n}(\mu_o-\overline x)^2
\end{align}
which means that the marginal posterior on $\sigma^2$ is an inverse Gamma with parameters
$$\frac{1}{2}(v_o+n,[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_on(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+n)])$$
This also follows from observing that, since
$$\overline{x}\mid\mu,\sigma\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,n^{-1}\sigma^2)\qquad
\mu\mid\sigma\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_o,n_o^{-1}\sigma^2)$$
then by marginalising in $\mu$
$$\overline{x}\mid\sigma\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_o,[n^{-1}+n_o^{-1}]\sigma^2)$$

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting the point :) In your last paragraph what do you mean with 'up to a multiplicative constant.' ?

Comment: How did you integrate $(1)$, did you use Mathematica or something else?

Comment: And so the other term  $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s+n_o\mu_o^2+n s^2]} e^{\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)]}$ is the marginal posterior of $\sigma^2$ right (I just want to be sure)?

Comment: Actually should that not depend only of $s$ and $s_o$? Can I rewrite $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[(v_o+(n-1)+n)s^2_1 ]}K$ , where $K$ represents the rest of the terms and $s^2_1=s^2_o+s^2$

Comment: How did you integrate respect to $\mu$, $\int_0^{\infty}(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n+1}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+n_o(\mu-\mu_o)^2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline
 x-\mu)^2]}d\mu$? I know that the marginal of $\sigma^2$ it's already calculated in your answer, but it'll be good to know the alternative version.

Comment: I was checking all again and I think there's a missing parameter in the Gamma function $\Gamma(\frac{v_o+n+1}{2})$ ? also in the Conversely part the $\sigma^{-1}$ should not be $\sigma^{-3}$ ?

Comment: Oh ok, thank you ^^ . I should delete the other question then?.

Comment: I have another question, probably not that related to the main question. What the parameters mean? Say, if $\alpha\to0 $ and $\beta\to0$ then what does that mean?

Comment: yes that's the case, it is $1/\sigma^2$

Comment: How did you passed from here $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_o\mu_o^2+n \overline x^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)]}$ to $(\sigma^2)^{-\frac{v_o+n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}[v_os_o^2+(n-1)s^2+n_ov_o(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+v_o)^2]}$ ? I could notice the only that changed from one to the other is $n_o\mu_o^2+n \overline x^2-(n_o\mu_o+n\overline x)^2/(n_o+n)$ to $n_ov_o(\overline x-\mu_o)^2/(n_o+v_o)^2$ though $v_o$ Is not in the first term. Also notice I've changed $s^2$ by $\overline x^2$ (I think it's a minor typo)